# Problem with API Routes not working in next js, (keep getting 404 not found) [I am new]

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel

I am using nextjs 13 and the postgresql provided by vercel, I have created a few routes, here's an example of one of them:
get-testcase.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';

export default async function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse
) {
  try {
    const { id } = request.query;
    const idString = Array.isArray(id) ? id[0]?.toString() : id?.toString();

    if (!idString) throw new Error('ID is required');

    const { rows } = await sql`SELECT * FROM Testcases WHERE ID = ${idString}`;

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return response.status(404).json({ error: 'Test case not found' });
    }

    const testCase = rows[0];

    return response.status(200).json({ testCase });
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching test case' });
  }
}
```

this file is located in app/api/get-testcase.ts

everything seems to be correct, but everytime I try using the route I get 404 not found.
here's what happens when I navigate to this route:
'http://localhost:3000/api/get-testcases'
*image attached below, again 404 not found*
[image: again 404 not found]
A similar thing is happening with the other postgresql routes, but I have some other routes which function properly.

Keep in mind that I am new to nextjs so if the problem is something trivial, I apologise.

I tried confirming the project directory, navigating to the route directly on the browser and using postman canary, consulted the docs and even gpt and I can't seem to find what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Next 13 and an app dir you'll need to setup your directory differently.
It has to be: `app/api/get-testcase/route.ts`.

Also, you'll have to export your handler for the HTTP methods you need, i.e.:

```
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Or setup each individually, e.g.:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
[...]
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { param } = await req.json()
[...]
}
```

Comment: Hello!! Thank you for your suggestions, it is working now, I am able to make requests properly, I am facing another issue, with this snippet of code that is inside a map function:

```try {
                    let getTestCaseResponse = await fetch(`/api/get-testcase?id=${id}`, {method: 'GET'});
                    let getTestCaseData = await getTestCaseResponse.json();
                    latestScore = getTestCaseData.testCase.latestscore;
                } catch (error) {
                    latestScore = "-";
                }```

Do you have any suggestions of what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Next.js App router documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#convention):

> Route Handlers are defined in a route.js|ts file inside the app directory:

In the code sample you provided, new "app router" conventions are mixed with old "pages router" conventions.

If you want to use new "app router", you should save your handler as `app/api/get-testcase/route.ts` AND change your export signature like this:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {}
```

where `Request` is just native Node.js Request class. No need to import `NextApiRequest` then.

You can also use old "pages router". In order to do that, just save your handler as `src/api/get-testscase.ts` and keep the export signature like you have:

```
export default async function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse
)
```